# How to get variable value whn using the contiues double quotes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
 var hdn_add_element_cnt = $("#hdn_add_element_cnt").val();

 alert(hdn_add_element_cnt);    

 $('#element_area').append("<div id=\'foobar\'>This is my text

 <div id=\'del_1\'   onclick=\'return delete_element(\"hdn_add_element_cnt\");\'>Remove</div></div>");


 function delete_element(t){
alert(t); -------------Am Getting String value instead of hdn_add_element_cnt count
//$("#"+del_1).remove();
//alert(t+hdn_add_element_cnt);
 }
```

am holding count in hdn_add_element_cnt variable, i want this count in delete_element function,

currently am getting the string instead of count value,

how to insert the variable value in double quotes,

Please advise

Comment: >  var app_str = "<div>New Element <a onclick=\"delete_element("+hdn_add_element_cnt+")\">Delete</a></div>"+hdn_add_element_cnt; finally i did one try, got expected, any way post your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the double quotes in the onClick handler.

Also - you don't need to escape all the single quotes.

Like this:

```
 $('#element_area').append("<div id='foobar'>This is my text

 <div id='del_1' onClick='return delete_element(hdn_add_element_cnt);'>Remove</div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element_area').append("<div id=\'foobar\'>This is my text
<div id=\'del_1\'   onclick=\'return delete_element(\"" + hdn_add_element_cnt + "\");\'>Remove</div></div>");
```

Comment: getting string, instead of number or count